# Angularjs:Getting rows from array that matches some condition

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an array look like this

```
var hospitals=[{"distric_id":"1","type":"c","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}]},
   {"distric_id":"1","type":"g","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}}]}
   ]
```

Now i need to get row from the array it satisfy some condition.
Here is the code snippet

```
 //loop through the array and fecth some rows based on some condition
function getHospitals(id,type){
  var hospitals=[{"district_id":"1","type":"c","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}]},
       {"district_id":"1","type":"g","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}}]}
       ]
  //return array of results
  return result;
}
```

`result` array contains rows from the `hospitals` array that matches condition
like
 `select *  from where district_id=id and type=type`
 So how can select a row from the above array that matches the above condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Lodash to do this.
https://lodash.com/docs#findWhere

From lodash:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.result(_.findWhere(users, { 'age': 36, 'active': true }), 'user');
// → 'barney'

_.result(_.findWhere(users, { 'age': 40, 'active': false }), 'user');
// → 'fred'
```

There are a lot of search functions in lodash: find() findIndex(), ...

Answer (score 0):

A full-fledged SQL parser and storage system based on JavaScript arrays does not currently exist. There is some deprecated and experimental stuff floating around like [this sql parser](https://github.com/forward/sql-parser) that only supports SELECT statements but I would strongly recommend against it.

Instead, you might want to take a look at [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) (or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)). They both have a lot of high-level utility functions that make working on arrays and other kinds of collections a whole lot easier.

E.g.

> select *  from where district_id=id and type=type

can be implemented like that:

`var matchingHospitals = _.where(hospitals, {district_id: id, type: type});`

NOTE: [`_.where`](https://lodash.com/docs#where) returns an array.

Also, if `_.where` does not cut it, there is also [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter), `_.find` and more...

Comment: Is any angularjs api for that?

Comment: @shammon It is entirely independent of Angular. You do not need anything Angular-specific, since your data is stored in plain JavaScript objects. There are many libraries out there that make working with JavaScript objects and arrays easier. Lodash and Underscore are the most popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's 'grep' function to this:

```
function getHospitals(id, type){
    var hospitals=[
        {"district_id":"1","type":"c","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}]},
        {"district_id":"1","type":"g","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}}]}
    ];

    //return array of results
    return $.grep(hospitals, function(e){
        return (e.district_id == id && e.type == type);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //loop through the array and return all rows satisfying the conditions
    function getHospitals(id,type){
  var hospitals=[{
    "district_id":"1","type":"c","details":[{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}]
  },{"district_id":"1","type":"g","details":{"name":"hello","address":"hello","number":"686678"}}];
  var matchingHospitals = []; //an array to save all the matching hospitals that satisfy the condition
  for(var i in hospitals){  //loop through the data
    var hospital = hospitals[i];
    if(hospital.district_id==id && hospital.type==type){ //check condition
      matchingHospitals.push(hospital);    //push into matching array
    }
  }

  //return array of results
  return matchingHospitals;   //return matching hospitals array
}
```

Test query:

```
getHospitals("1","c")
```

Comment: Updated, included the test code. The code is using pure JavaScript and no extra library or plugin is required. 
The code can be shortened but I like simplicity and better understand-ability :)